# Unpivot Access Data Table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, unpivot

Good afternoon,

I would like to unpivot an Access Table. I have almost one hundred of columns in Access and one column with the ID and I would like to unpivot, considering all the columns except de ID into one column called "type" (for example).

[image]

How could I get it from Access? It doesnt matter if is by a SQL query or VBA.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Thank you but none of the result are useful for my problem. The majority resolve it with Select... from... Union (it is not possible due to the large amount of columns) or through a VBA query that have the columns with a numeric order or date (1999, 2000, 2001, etc. as an example).

Comment: If you already tried some of these approaches, it's useful to describe exactly what you tried, and what exact problem(s) you had while trying them.  No point in folks here proposing things you've already ruled out for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the approaches with `SELECT ...` do not work for the OP one could try to do it with "stupid" code. Let's assume you have the tables `tblSource` and `tblTarget` where `tblTarget` has the fields `ID`, `type` and `val` and `ID` is the first field in tblSource. Then the following code will "unpivot" the data

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub stupidUnpivot()

    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim rsSrc As Recordset
    Set rsSrc = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblSource")
    
    Dim rsTrg As Recordset
    Set rsTrg = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblTarget")
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    rsSrc.MoveFirst
    
    Do
        With rsTrg
            ' every row in tblSoruce regardless of the number of columns
            ' will be written to tblTarget in the fields ID, type and val
            For i = 1 To rsSrc.Fields.Count - 1
                .AddNew
                .Fields("ID").Value = rsSrc.Fields(0).Value
                .Fields("type").Value = rsSrc.Fields(i).Name
                .Fields("val").Value = rsSrc.Fields(i).Value
                .Update
            Next i
        
        End With
        rsSrc.MoveNext
    Loop Until rsSrc.EOF

End Sub
```